# TFS 2010- Getting a specific version of a file from checked-in task

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, tfs

How to get specific version of a file from checked-in task?

When I right click on a file and select history. It shows me “change set” and when right click on “change set” and select “get this version” then it takes other files also of that version. But I need to take specific version of only one file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you right click on your file in source control explorer and select Advanced->Get Specific Version you can select which version of the file you want. you can search by changeset etc from there.

[image]
or by command line by date:

```
 tf.exe get c:\myproject\mybranch\myfile.txt /v:D"2013-11-23"
```

or by changeset number:

```
 tf.exe get c:\myproject\mybranch\myfile.txt /v:C12345
```

you can see the changeset numbers by the History command:

```
tf.exe history c:\myproject\mybranch\myfile.txt
```

Comment: I found only these optins:
View,
Get Latest Version,
Get Specific Version...,
Check out for Edit...,
Lock...,
Delete,
Rename,
....
.....

Comment: I added a picture from my visual studio.

Comment: Get Specific Version is the one you want

Comment: yes, In your screenshot Advanced option is available but in my case it is not available. I am using Visual studio 2010 and you are using Visual studio 2012. So version difference might be the reason.

Comment: VS 2010 doesn't have the advanced menu, but its not too far off.  see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181416(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Yes, In get specific Version there is an option is date by which I can take it. Thanks

Comment: The link you have provided to me says that: 

Note:- **This operation gets every version control item in the changeset. Team Foundation version control does not let you get individual items from a changeset**.

Comment: But I need Individual item from a changeset not entire changeset.

Comment: How come your get specific and other commands are under an advanced menu. Mine are all bunched into the main contexdt menu.

Comment: I have no idea. What version/edition of visual studio do you have?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010 Professional.

Comment: You're right, in 2010 there was no Advanced menu, but its still Get Specific Version that will get you updates on only that file.