# Get specific version of the file from TFS

Tags: c#, .net, tfs

I am trying to download files from TFS by following code:

```
    TeamFoundationServer tfsServer = new TeamFoundationServer(options.TfsUri);
    VersionControlServer vcServer = (VersionControlServer)tfsServer.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer));
    if (vcServer == null)
        throw new ApplicationException("Invalid vcServer");
    Item i;
    foreach (TFSObject obj in TfsObjectList)
    {
        if (!obj.isFolder)
        {
            i = vcServer.GetItem(obj.tfsPath);
            i.DownloadFile(obj.localPath);
            Console.WriteLine(obj.localPath + " is downloaded");
        }
    }
```

Everything is working as expected however it is always looking for the latest version of the file. How can I get the version of the file that it checked in before or with the check-in # XXXXX? The file could be modified after this check-in...

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20354750/tfs-2010-getting-a-specific-version-of-a-file-from-checked-in-task

Comment: I am asking how to do that from C# code, not from Visual Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your single argument [`GetItem(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138919(v=vs.120).aspx), gets the information for the `Item` at the specified path at the latest version.

You can specify a [`VersionSpec`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versionspec(v=vs.120).aspx) to download a particular version.  For example, to download changeset 42:

```
vcServer.GetItem(obj.tfsPath, new ChangesetVersionSpec(42));
```